# C# MongoDbDriver migrating obsolete Count to replacement methods

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

For some time we've been getting warnings in our code:

> Warning   CS0618  'IMongoCollection.Count(FilterDefinition, CountOptions, CancellationToken)' is obsolete: 'Use CountDocuments or EstimatedDocumentCount instead.'

So we want to "update". However, we're running into performance problems. Which seem to have already reported in 2018 on [Jira (mongoDb driver issue tracker)](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1638).

I did some tests myself and found the following for a small collection,which already shows the differences:

- Count returns 6600 and took 12 ms.
- CountDocuments returns 6600 and took 25 ms.
- EstimatedDocumentCount returns 6600 and took 2 ms.

But then for a big collection:

- Count returns 2721199 and took 12 ms.
- CountDocuments returns 2721199 and took 196406 ms.
- EstimatedDocumentCount returns 2721199 and took 4 ms.

That's 196 seconds! **16367x** slower! *Totally* unacceptable...

One could argue "Then just use `EstimatedDocumentCount`". However, `EstimatedDocumentCount` doesn't offer the same interface: i.e. you cannot filter/there's no filter parameter or option.

And if you would try the something like `collection.Find(...).EstimatedDocumentCount()` that doesn't work, as `IFindFluent` doesn't offer an `EstimatedDocumentCount` method.
And we *do* want to filter often.

What's up with this? How can they deprecate a functionality and not replace it with something good?

Does anybody know how to fix this?

edit: Like @Joe suggested, I added a filter (didn't do that before). Now I get different results:

- Count returns 2060277 and took ~434 ms.
- CountDocuments returns 2060277 and took ~575 ms.
- *EstimateDocumentCount is not an option when filtering*

Weird. But anyhow,  CountDocuments is still 25% slower, which is significant. Can this be fixed? (The query is already using an index)

Comment: In your tests, did you time `count` both with and without a filter?

Comment: @Joe wait whaaaat? Good point. I didn't. That makes a BIG difference. What's up with that?

Comment: The filtered Count/CountDocuments that took over 100ms should both be logged.  Do the log entries provide any insight into what might be different?

Comment: @Joe how can I access the logs? I found they are stored in a file. But the mongoDB is on an enterprise server, so I cannot access the filesystem. I only have the credentials for the DB. Can I access the log from there?

Comment: @Joe additional: I can have admin access is seems. But it's a local server (i.e. not Atlas). I can only use a DB viewer like Compass or Robo 3T

Comment: You might be able to use database profiling to store the query metadata in the system.profile collection, but I'm not 100% sure it will contain the same data as the file.

Comment: @Joe hmm, even the admin account doesn't seem to have (access to) a system collection, let alone system.profile. Are those my only options?

Comment: system.profile may not exist if the profiler has never been enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Previously, calling `Count` implicitly (and silently) used the `EstimatedDocumentCount` behavior when no filter was provided, and the `CountDocuments` behavior when one was provided.

It is called "Estimated" because all it does is retrieve the document count from the collection metadata.  That value is *usually* correct, but there are a number of things that can cause that metadata value to drift from the actual count.

This was a source of confusion in the past, and MongoDB apparently got tired of responding "works as designed" and recommending the use of a filter that would match all documents to get the accurate count, so they split `Count` into two separate functions that explicitly use only one of those behaviors.

This means that you now have a choice.  If you want to get the count of all documents in the collection, you can call `CountDocuments` to get the up to the minute completely accurate answer, or you can call `EstimatedDocumentCount` to really quickly pull the hopefully correct metadata.

Since getting the count from metadata is literally just retrieving a single integer, it cannot support filtering.

Comment: Thank I'll double check this first. I updated the numbers (had startup behavior that I didn't take into account) It still seems that `CountDocuments` is 25% slower... can that be fixed?

Comment: @JHBonarius i think you'd be able to speed up `CountDocuments()` by creating indexes for the fields used in the filter so that mongo doesn't have to do a `COLLSCAN` and can simply do a `COUNT_SCAN` using the index.

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ there already seems to be an index on the field I was querying. Doesn't solve the 25% slower issue.

Comment: 25% slower might be due to cache or other factors.  Does changing the order of execution and/or immediately rerunning the test show the same result?